# SQL Reporting Services email subscription configuration

Tags: email, sql-server, ssrs

I'm trying to configure a Microsoft SSRS 2014 server to send out emails.  As far as I can tell all the settings are correct in RS Configuration Manager, and I can send an email from the server itself using TELNET commands to our SMTP provider (so I believe it's unlikely to be connectivity).

The error in the SSRS logs looks like a DNS error, but I can resolve the name of "mydomain.com" on the SSRS server using NSLOOKUP.  (This is not the real domain name, just illustrating)

Where else should I be looking?

Thanks

Error:

```
emailextension!WindowsService_9!4b8!06/29/2020-10:00:12:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mydomain.com'
```

Comment: Has the machine name changed after you installed SSRS? See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac51ab00-2aab-499f-aae9-76b723aed2dc/ssrs-error-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thanks Doug, I'll check

Answer (score 0):

You can verify setting in the Extension `Name="Report Server Email"` section of your rsreportserver.config file.